# jQuery Date Validation while explicitly type on the input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

jQuery Date Validation while explicitly type on the input field instead of selecting from datepicker

I just want minimum date as today. i.e I don't want to select future dates.

In date picker i disabled the future dates.But, when i type the date in the field it is accepting the future date.

Here is my jQuery Code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({  maxDate: new Date(),dateFormat: 'MM/DD/YYYY' });
  jQuery('.fa-calendar').click(function() {
    jQuery("#datepicker").focus();
  });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you add `readonly=""` on input field? So that user will not allow to enter a date.. He only need to select from datepicker

Comment: Have you tried using `maxDate : 0`?

Comment: Hey, Mathi checkout my answer. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think probably you are looking for something like this. you can give input date by typing and validate it that not greater than today. I would also suggest that to use your datepicker field readonly so that user can not give invalid input as @Mufi said in the comment.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker,#datepickerReadonly").datepicker({  
   maxDate: new Date(),
   dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
 changeYear:true,
 changeMonth:true,
  });
  
  $('.fa-calendar').click(function() {
    $("#datepicker").focus();
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="datepicker">
<input type="button" id="" value="check" onclick="check_();"/><br>
Read Only Example: <br><input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="datepickerReadonly">

<script>
function check_(){
 if(new Date($('#datepicker').val()) > new Date()){
  alert("you are not allowed to select future date");
  $('#datepicker').val('');
 }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

      jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({                         
                    dateFormat: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                    maxDate: '+10Y',
                    minDate: '+0M',
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    yearRange: "-0:+10", });

      jQuery('.fa-calendar').click(function() {
        jQuery("#datepicker").focus();
      });
    });
```

This example allow you to select maximum `10 years` previous year to `Today`.